# how to get the stdout and stderr from Popen in a line by line format?

Tags: python

I am running the Python script below. When I print stdout and stderr, they are printed as each letter (please see below). How do I get stdout and stderr to print in the original format per line?

```
cmd = r"""python ./script.py"""
print cmd
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = proc.communicate()
for line in output:
    print "in stdout"
    print line
    if 'Onlycloned' in line:
        print "OnlyclonedRadars line matched"
        #logger.info('OnlyclonedRadars line matched')
        radars = line
        radarlist = radars.split(':')[1].strip()
        #radars = 37142113  
    for line in error:
        print "in stderr"
        print line
```

**Output:**

```
in stderr
2
in stderr
0
in stderr
:
in stderr
5
in stderr
8
in stderr
:
in stderr
4
in stderr
5
in stderr

in stderr
r
```

Comment: Please reduce your code down to a minimal example. i.e. Remove the commented lines and any other code that is not necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Stdout and stderr aren't lists - so there's no need to iterate over them. They're likely to just be strings or bytes. If you need to iterate you'll need to split as appropriate.